# Rewrite users to different pages with nuxt 3 middleware

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I need completely different page structures in my Nuxt 3 product page and I have a site that is statically generated.

With the following folder structure we can access a product page for desktop in one of two ways:

1. For Desktop `/_viewport/desktop/products/t-shirt`
2. For Mobile `/_viewport/mobile/products/t-shirt`

```js
/pages
  /_viewport
    /desktop
      /products
        /[handle].vue
    /mobile
      /products
        /[handle].vue
```

Since this is a statically generated site `SSG`, the routing takes place on the front end.

How can I create some middleware so that if the user visits `/products/t-shirt`, and a variable `isMobile = true` they will land on `/_viewport/mobile/products/t-shirt` while showing only `/products/t-shirt` in the url?

For example,

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  const isMobile = true

  if (to.path.includes('products') && isMobile) {
    // send them to /_viewport/mobile/products/t-shirt
    // but make sure it is re-written to show 
    // /products/t-shirt in the url 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need use several routes for this?
You can just use the [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) or media queries for this case for example:

```
<template>
<div v-if="isMobile" class="mobile-layout">Content for mobile</div>
<div v-else class="desktop-layout">Content for desktop</div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.mobile-layout {
  display: block;

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
}
.desktop-layout {
  display: none;

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have already found a proper solution to this which is netlify url rewriting. For reasons too long to post here it gets too messy to use media queries and conditional rendering.